# ColumnOffset in VBA loop not working

Tags: vba, excel, loops

Trying to use a simple Do while loop to cycle through a set of columns, and to add the value of the cell three rows above to a collection, until the table ends.

```
Function test()

Dim r As Range, first As Range, coll As New Collection, ab As String

Set r = Range("H14")

Do While r <> ""
    coll.Add r.Offset(RowOffSet:=-3).Value
    r = r.Offset(ColumnOffSet:=1)
Loop

End Function
```

For some reason, the ColumnOffset doesn't work. No errors, but when I check the value in the locals window the column doesn't change, and the loop just repeats on that column, and then it obviously crashes. If I replace it with a RowOffset it works completely fine.

Comment: You need to set r. It is a range object.

Comment: @Scott Craner Thank you sir